need to add error level or set variable to PowerShell command
How can I add error levels to the PowerShell command below or set up a variable based on the results.
I need to command to return a value as to whether to hard drive is an SSD or a regular hard drive.
If it is an SSD go to end of file if it is not an SSD open a message box that hard drive needs to be replaced.
powershell.exe "exit ((get-physicaldisk).MediaType) -ne 'SSD'" && echo SSD
Thanks for your help with this this
I have not been able to get a to return any error level.
The command will echo if an SSD but will exit if not and SSD

U could wrap it in a try-catch and throw an exeption if not ssd:
powershell.exe -Command "try { if ((Get-PhysicalDisk).MediaType -ne 'SSD') { throw 'One or more disks are not SSD.' } else { Write-Output 'SSD' } } catch { Write-Error $_.Exception.Message; exit 1 }"


Tried the command this error ==>
try { if ((Get-PhysicalDisk).MediaType -ne 'SSD') { throw 'One or more disks are not SSD.' } else { Write-Output 'SSD'
} } catch { Write-Error $_.Exception.Message; exit 1 } : One or more disks are not SSD.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException

This sets the errorlevel.
powershell Get-PhysicalDisk | findstr SSD
echo %errorlevel%

0

